# Merge Two Columns from Same Data Frame to New Column Depending on Condition of Null Values

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

So here is my data:

```
colA    colB  
1       NA
2       3
3       4
4       NA
```

What I want to do is using these two columns I want to create a new column that combines the values from each. It will essentially take all the values from column B but in the event of a null value it will take the value from column A instead. The output will look like this:

```
colA   colB   newColumn
1      NA     1
2      3      3
3      4      4
4      NA     4
```

My code so far looks like this but it broke RStudio. As I typed out my question here it is literally still running:

```
for(i in 1:length(data$colB)){
  if(is.na(data$colB[i])){
  data$newColumn <- data$colA}
  else{
    data$newColumn <- data$colB
  }
}
```

Comment: your code runs well. Not sure why it is still running in your machine. Restart your session and it should run fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so assuming your data is as follows:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1 <- read.table(text = "colA    colB  
1       NA
2       3
3       4
4       NA",header=1)
```

A one liner resolving your issue using `ifelse`:

```
df1$newColumn <- ifelse(is.na(df1$colB), df1$colA, df1$colB)
```

and your bug is because you need to index your replacements so instead of `data$newColumn <- data$colA` you should have `data$newColumn[i] <- data$colA[i]` and the same on the else statement. But it is always better to use vectorized functions such as `ifelse`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `dplyr::coalesce` is a shorthand for this type of operation. It works on multiple vectors, so if you had a `colC` that might also have values to funnel in, you could add that to the call. You provide vectors in order of precedence, so it will return the first non-`NA` value it sees.

```r
data <- data.frame(
  colA = 1:4,
  colB = c(NA_integer_, 3L, 4L, NA_integer_)
)

data$new_column <- dplyr::coalesce(data$colB, data$colA)
data
#>   colA colB new_column
#> 1    1   NA          1
#> 2    2    3          3
#> 3    3    4          4
#> 4    4   NA          4
```